# How to calculate a random point inside a cube

Tags: math, vector, 3d

I'm trying to figure out the math to find a random point inside a cube.

I have something small but it can't take into account the rotation of the cube.

Here are some images of my results.

[image]

[image]

Here you can see the cube is rotated to some degree but when I generate some points it retains the shape as if the cube was normal (I think the term is called axis aligned but I'm not sure).

I'm using a Vector to represent the extent of the cube but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the points to follow it when it's rotated.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I would do this?

EDIT1:

[image]

Now its misaligned and it goes even weirder when I rotate it sideways.

Can someone walk me through it from the beginning? I think my base line math is all wrong to begin with.

Comment: Generate the points in the straight position then apply the rotation.

Comment: Ok i think i did what you suggested but its all out of alignment.

Comment: I added an image to main thread

Comment: Check the origin of the coordinates.

Comment: I was adding the worldlocation of the cube before rotating it. Adding it to the rotated vector has aligned it properly.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, it was really bugging me. Convert your comment to an answer and ill check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the points in the straight position then apply the rotation (also check the origin of the coordinates).